# Excel VBA: Can't Access Form Control?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the latest Office 365 Excel on OS X.  I've created a List Box Form Control (ActiveX controls don't seem to be available in OS X), called `wb_from`:

[image]

I'm trying to access this List Box from VBA using this code:

```
Sub my_Import()

    Dim MailStr As String

    MailStr = ""

    If wb_from.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No User Selected"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    For i = 0 To (wb_from.Items.Count - 1)
        If wb_from.Selected(i) Then
            MailStr = MailStr & wb_from.Items.Item(i) & "; "
        End If
    Next i
    a = 100

End Sub
```

Excel is giving me an `object required` error:

[image]

How can I correct this?

Comment: What cell did you link that control to via Format Control? That cell address should be used in your code.

Comment: Try to Access with Shapes("List Box 1").OLEFormat.Object

Comment: I couldn't get the `Shapes` approach to work yet, but @RetiredGeek the solution you proposed worked. If you'd like to post it as an answer I will mark it accepted. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What cell did you link that control to via Format Control? That cell address should be used in your code.